# android popup window doesn't show?

Tags: android, popup

I have a popup window that gets called from a listener in my fragment. Before it was called from a button press and it displayed immediately. However, after moving the method that creates it to a custom listener, it no longer pop ups instantly. But rather only after a click event or scroll event occurs anywhere on the screen. I'm guessing the screen needs to be refreshed somehow to show the popup? Here's my creating code:

```
  /***POP UP WINDOW CODE***/

PopupWindow popupMessage;
PopupWindow pw;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void popupInit(){

       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Get screen dimensions to set the window size
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_interview, null, false);

         // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, (int) (width*(0.8)), (int) (height*(0.8)), true);

        // display the popup in the center
        layout.post(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                 pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                 pw.update(0, 0, pw.getWidth(), pw.getHeight());
               }
        });
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried running it outside the Runnable?

Comment: It worked! Do you know why that would cause a problem?

Comment: I typically do not work with Runnable but I believe they are used to delay and this may be missing a handler.  Are you trying to delay the view?

Comment: I had actually gotten most of that from sample code so I wasn't sure if it was needed or not, but I left it in.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to delay the popup just do the following:

```
pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
pw.update(0, 0, pw.getWidth(), pw.getHeight());
```